# Justify one line text with vertical display

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to display my vertical text in justify mode, so that my text takes the whole space in the h1 block where it is located.
I'm also not allowed to use js in this.

```css
section {
    text-align: left;
}

section > header {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}

section article {
    float: left;
    width: 42%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
section article div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col_container {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.vertical_header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom:-1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;    
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    left: 0;
    top: 205px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
}

.vertical_header:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.image_container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.info h2{
    font-size: 1em
}

.info h2, .info h3, .info p {
    text-align: center;
}

.info h3, .info p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.info p {
    line-height: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="col_container">
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1 class="vertical_header">STAFF</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="image_container">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Bill Smith</h2>
        <h3>Producer</h3>
        <p>Awesome corp</p>
        <p>555 67 67</p>
        <p>555 90 90</p>
        <p>CONTACT</p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Basically I'd like that the "STAFF" word being as long as the grey block height, I've seen the hacks using this css:

```
h1 {
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}

h1:after {
    content: ”;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But it doesn't work, do someone have an idea?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: you need to understand how justify works as it's not like you expect

Comment: You could put spaces in between you letters - then your justify will work: https://jsfiddle.net/6s74oprn/

Comment: I've read that it works only for texts having multiple lines and I'd like it for one line.

Comment: Can you figure out that actually what you want?

Comment: It's what I wanted, thanks Pete!

Answer (score 0):

Use css property **letter-spacing**

```css
section {
    text-align: left;
}

section > header {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}

section article {
    float: left;
    width: 42%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
section article div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col_container {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.vertical_header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom:-1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;    
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    left: 0;
    top: 205px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
letter-spacing: 40px;
}

.vertical_header:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.image_container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.info h2{
    font-size: 1em
}

.info h2, .info h3, .info p {
    text-align: center;
}

.info h3, .info p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.info p {
    line-height: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="col_container">
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1 class="vertical_header">STAFF</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="image_container">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Bill Smith</h2>
        <h3>Producer</h3>
        <p>Awesome corp</p>
        <p>555 67 67</p>
        <p>555 90 90</p>
        <p>CONTACT</p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with having spaces between letters,You can use `letter-spacing` 
as given below..Hope it helps

```css
section {
    text-align: left;
}

section > header {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
}

section article {
    float: left;
    width: 42%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
section article div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col_container {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.vertical_header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom:-1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;    
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    left: 0;
    top: 205px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    letter-spacing: 37px;
}

.vertical_header:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.image_container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.info h2{
    font-size: 1em
}

.info h2, .info h3, .info p {
    text-align: center;
}

.info h3, .info p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.info p {
    line-height: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col_container">
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1 class="vertical_header">STAFF</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="image_container">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Bill Smith</h2>
        <h3>Producer</h3>
        <p>Awesome corp</p>
        <p>555 67 67</p>
        <p>555 90 90</p>
        <p>CONTACT</p>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```